# is amf0 still used? Is there any backward compatibility for amf0 in amf3?

Tags: amf

Is amf0 still used ?

Is there any backward compatibility for amf0 in amf3?

Which encoding does the current version of Adobe flex use---amf0 or amf3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amf0 is for as2. 
amf3 is for amf3, though you can switch to amf0 if needed.

So amf0 is seldom used

yes, there is backward compatibility

flex uses amf3.

Comment: AMF encoding occurs at the NetConnection; All objects in Flash can be encoded to AMF0 and AMF3.  The only difference is how they are reconstructed.  For example Vector will not reconstruct to a Vector in AMF0.  AMF0 is by far the most computationally efficient of the two.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2015, AMF0 is still widely used as the metadata format for FLV files.

While the MPEG-4 Part 14 (or simply MP4) file format has largely superseded FLV for most workflows, it is still used when publishing live video to RTMP servers like Adobe Media Server, Wowza, or nginx-rtmp.

It is therefore used in FLV events that are handled by NetStream instances, like this:

```
netStream.onMetaData = function(myMeta) { 
  for (var i in myMeta) { 
      trace(i + ":\t" + myMeta[i]) 
  } 
};
```